# How do I install Mira_Tools addon?

Tags: add-on

I've put the MiraTools directory in the addons - nothing I can do will make it show in the addons ion user prefs. The *.py files are there, including *init*.py, but nogo. I can see all the other addons in that directory enabled & otherwise, vut not Mira_tools. Anyong got any ideas? I'm using Blender 2.78.

> ok I am using the User Prefs, I've added addons before & they work. This one remains invisible.
>
> I'm aware there are other addons in the pack. I have found the issue. I uninstalled V2.78, reinstalled it - still nogo. Then went to V2.79, still nogo. BUT on another machine using either 2.78 or 2.79, it works great. The issue is 32/64 bit OS (Windows) Mira works fine on my 32 bit machine. I have come across this before - there is still some bug between 32/64 bit directory listings (I'm sure it's an OS thing) where some files become invisible in that they won't "parse" but you can still see the listing in a dir. I've now seen this about 4 times, it screws me up once every two years, and it's still there. So - I appreciate your help, problem solved and - don't get caught!

Comment: have you reloaded blender after, or clicked the "refresh" button in the preferences/addon panel? I just tried with 2.76 and, apart a warning about using a version older than 2.78, I can find them and once activated, they load a toolbar tab with various tools...

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos there *is* something different about it, since the ZIP shipped by the creators contains more than just a Blender add-on.

Answer (score 4):

From the information available [on the Mira-Tools Wiki page](https://github.com/mifth/mifthtools/wiki/Mira-Tools):

- Download the [zip archive for the development version](https://github.com/mifth/mifthtools/archive/master.zip).
- Unzip the downloaded file.
- Copy `mira_tools/blender/addons/mira_tools` folder into your [user addons folder](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html#platform-dependent-paths).
- Refresh Blender's add-ons and enable the add-on "MiraTools".

Apparently the ZIP they ship contains all kinds of data, it's not just a Blender add-on. This means that you cannot install it via Blender itself, but have to do it manually. Their [issue #22](https://github.com/mifth/mifthtools/issues/22) also complains about this.

Comment: the wiki page says to copy "mira_tools" folder, not "mifth_tools"... I used that and it worked even on my 2.76b...

Comment: I had written mira tools. Someone, on correction, changed it

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem, and found that all the tools are available in edit mode. I don't know if this helps anyone.